# Difficulty Finding $A^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1& -1 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 &  1\\
\end{bmatrix}$. Compute $A^k$.

## My attempt

I'm trying to compute $A^k$ using [this approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2688250/how-to-calculate-square-matrix-to-power-n-with-induction) as follows:
$$ 
A=I+N=
\begin{bmatrix}
1& 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  1
\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
0& -1 & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 &  0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with
$$
N^2=
\begin{bmatrix}
0& 0 & -1\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  0\\
\end{bmatrix}, \, \text{and} \, \,
N^3=
\begin{bmatrix}
0& 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then,
$$
A^2=(I+N)^2=I+2N+N^2, \\
A^3=(I+N)^3=I+3N+3N^2, \\
A^4=(I+N)^4=I+4N+6N^2, \\
A^5=(I+N)^5=I+5N+10N^2, \\
A^6=(I+N)^5=I+6N+15N^2,
$$

By induction, we can see $A^k=(I+N)^k=I+kN+f[k]N^2$. But, I couldn't figure out what $f[k]$ is. Any help?

Comment: binomial coefficient $k$ choose $2,$ which become $k(k-1)/2$

Comment: @WillJagy Exactly! It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this. Take the exponential function $e^{tA}$, where $t$ is some parameter
$$e^{tA}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{t^kA^k}{k!}=e^{t(I+N)}= e^{tI}e^{tN}=e^t\left[I+tN+\frac{(tN)^2}{2}\right]$$
where we used the matrix identity $e^{A+B}=e^Ae^B$ that is valid when 
matrices $A$ and $B$ commute.
Since the functions $t^k$ are linearly independent, we obtain
$$A^k=I+kN+\frac{k(k-1)}{2}N^2$$

Comment: That's even a better compact approach. However, I did not get how $t^2$ became $k(k-1)$. What is it that you mean with "the functions $t^k$ are linearly independent"?

Comment: @Lod, you have to expand the exponential on the right side, the coefficients of $t^k$ on both sides of the equation have to be equal. The linear independence you can see from this: If you assume $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kt^k=0$ is valid for all $t$, this implies all $a_k=0$. To see this just take the $k$-th order derivative and then replace $t=0$.

Answer (score 3):

You have written $A=I+N$, and you know that $N^3$ (and hence all higher powers) are zero.  If $X$ and $Y$ are two matrices that commute with each other, then you can still use the bionomial theorem:
$$(X+Y)^n=\sum_{i+j=n}\binom{n}{i} X^i Y^j$$

Because $I$ commutes with $N$, and because all the higher powers of $N$ vanish, we can apply the formula to get

$$(I+N)^n=\sum_{i+j=n}\binom{n}{j} N^j=I+nN+\binom{n}{2}N^2$$